# Git search commit with specific unicode char in content

Tags: regex, git, unicode

I want to get all commits with a specific unicode char (https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+200B) : Zero Width Space (U+200B).

```
git log -G 'regex'
```

This command should give me all commits with content that match the regex ([Git Doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt)).

I want to catch Zero Width Space but the following command returns me an empty list :

```
git ls -G '\u200b'
```

But, I have some commits with this type of character. `git diff` gives me :

```
-       path(r'v1/status<U+200B>/<str:key>', views.status, name="status<U+200B>"),
```

What's the way to search for unicode char in commits ?

Comment: Try `\xE2\x80\x8B`

Comment: It returns empty result

Comment: Are you sure that `<U+200B>` is not saved as a string? (to me it seems it is part of a template engine)

Comment: Yes, Git returns an empty result with git log -S "<U+200B>" and git log -G "<U+200B>"

Answer (score 2):

I could only get it to work with the help of [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), i.e. `$'\u200b'`:

```
zb@db:/tmp$ mkdir so70109544
zb@db:/tmp$ cd so70109544/
zb@db:/tmp/so70109544$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/so70109544/.git/
zb@db:/tmp/so70109544$ perl -e 'print "\xe2\x80\x8b"' > test.txt
zb@db:/tmp/so70109544$ git add test.txt
zb@db:/tmp/so70109544$ git ci -m "test"
[master (root-commit) 4775358] test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
zb@db:/tmp/so70109544$ git log -G $'\u200b'
commit 47753580a0e8e32af4e6c272d7ffdf0170f5bdd2 (HEAD -> master)
Author: zb <zb@somewhere.xyz>
Date:   Thu Nov 25 12:34:04 2021 +0100

    test
```